# Reset Enable password ASA 5505 via ASDM

Tags: firewall, passwords, password-management, password-recovery

I have an ASA firewall setup, but i have forgot the enable password; I have the admin password anyway.
**I am not trying to reset password using rommon; Please dont suggest confreg break**
I saw an user named enable_15 in ASDM, but resetting this password also did not work.

Via **CLI**:
Logged on with admin credentials:
user: admin
pass: ******

```
ASA> login
ASA>
username: admin
password: ******
ASA# conf terminal
ASA(conf)# no enable password level 1
```

Tried this, but when i check running config, i still see encrypted password for enable.
Also tried setting a new enable password- it too did not work.

**Another wierd thing: my admin credentials somehow work as enable password**
but trying to reset the enable password did not work

*What im looking forward into:

 1. Remove enable password

OR

 2. Reset enable password.*

Answer (score -1):

If your admin credentials work as the enable password...then that would be the encrypted enable password you are seeing right? enable_15 is always listed in users - its like the built in Administrator account in windows.